# Calling Windows10 Calculator on a Java Process?

Tags: java, windows, process

I'm a student who just started learning multi-thread programming based on Java.

As one of my first exercises, I was told to create a process that executes the windows calculator, then wait until the process is finished, then send a message. This is an extract of the code I did.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("calc.exe");
p.waitFor();
System.out.println("Process finished");
```

When I execute it, the Windows 10 calculator opens, then I get the *"Process finished"* message. I didn't know why I got the message when the process was still running, as the calculator was open, so I tried to run the exact same code but with the *"notepad.exe"* as the command to execute.

This time the result of the execution was the expected: I didn't get the message until I closed the notepad.

I tried to open other **Windows 10** default programs, as *"explorer.exe"* and some worked the way it is supposed to work and others didn't.

**My thoughts** on the way it works are that *"explorer.exe"* or *"calc.exe"* work like some kind of launcher, so when they receive a process executing them, they create their own processes that I don't control with the Java program. That's **complete speculation** made by me.

The **actual question** is: Why does that happen? How does Windows 10 Calculator and other programs work in terms of processes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Process#waitFor()` returns `int` value, which is actually the exit code (i.e. `errorlevel`) of the process.

Your code fails in cases when started process returns non-zero `errorlevel` and works "correct" (i.e. as expected) otherwise. You can check it by running batch file below:

```
@echo off
calc.exe
REM explorer.exe
echo Error level: %errorlevel%
```

It will return on your environment non-zero `errorlevel` output for **calc.exe** and **explorer.exe**, and `0` for **notepad.exe**.

On my environment (*Windows 7*) **calc.exe** also returns `0` and your code snippet works as expected.

Also please take into account that some programs might return non-zero exit code in success cases - it is not something stricted.

---

Based on this and the fact that the first exercise shouldn't be too complex - assume that your code snippet is the answer.

If regardless this you still need to find a solution, you can do so (batch commands here, not *Java*):

1. Run **calc.exe**:

   `calc.exe`
2. Find *PID* of the **calc.exe** process:

   `tasklist /v /fo csv | findstr /i "calc.exe"`
3. Run infinite check of the process by *PID* with `break;` when process is not presented anymore, e.g. using the command (assuming `PID = 1111`):

   `tasklist /fi "pid eq 1111"`